# How can I embed my GitHub profile to my website using iframe?

Tags: html, github, iframe

How can I embed my GitHub profile to my website using an iframe or there is another method to do so? I am using below code but unable to get the result.

```
<iframe width="50%" height="400px" src="github.com/dt9819?tab=repositories/"; style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);-moz-transform-scale(0.5);"></iframes>
```

Comment: <iframe width="50%" height="400px" src="https://github.com/dt9819?tab=repositories/" style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);-moz-transform-scale(0.5);"></iframes>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** you can't because it violates the 
Content Security Policy Directive: `frame-ancestors 'none'`

If you want to include your Github profile in a website, you can always try GithubIO for free.

```html
<iframe style="height:300px; width:300px;" src="https://github.com/renielcanlas">
<b>IFrame is NOT available here</b>
</iframe>

<iframe style="height:300px; width:300px;" src="https://renielcanlas.github.io">
<b>IFrame is available here</b>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you can have a look at this nice little project:
https://lab.lepture.com/github-cards/

[image: Github-cards-example]

Comment: Hm, this library does sadly not work on dynamic rendering libraries like react or vuejs, any alternatives?